# Combining 2 arrays into a dictionary in Xcode 6, swift?, with corresponding index values)

Tags: swift, dictionary

In my app, I have 2 arrays which are in use a lot, an array that stores score values as an Integer, and another array that stores dates in the format "mm/dd/yy". These arrays are continuously being appended, and the indexes of these arrays correspond to each other, for example, index 0 of dates array corresponds to index 0 of score array. I want these arrays to be turned into a dictionary upon when a second screen loads(these are global variables). For example, these are the type of values in each array.

```
score == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
dates == ["7/12/15","7/12/15","7/12/15","7/12/15","7/13/15","7/13/15","7/13/15","7/13/15","    7/14/15"]
```

What I want to happen, is that upon viewDidLoad(), this gets created.

```
var scoreDatesDictionary = [
"7/12/15": [1,2,3,4]
"7/13/15": [5,6,7,8]
"7/14/15": [9]
]
```

In its essence, the two arrays have corresponding values, (firstArray[0]) corresponds to (secondArray[0]). I am trying to make it that in the secondArray(dates), identical strings get matched up in a dictionary with their corresponding index values. I may not make much sense, but the sample code I provided should work. I spent a lot of time working with this, and I can't find a solution.

Comment: You provided no sample code, so I'm not sure what it is that you should expect to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working off @Leo's correct answer, here's a version that makes use of `enumerate` and the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to do this more cleanly:

For **Swift 1.2:**

```
let score = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
let dates = ["7/12/15","7/12/15","7/12/15","7/12/15","7/13/15","7/13/15","7/13/15","7/13/15"," 7/14/15"]
var dic = [String:[Int]]()

for (index, date) in enumerate(dates) {
    dic[date] = (dic[date] ?? []) + [score[index]]
}
print(dic)  // prints "[7/12/15: [1, 2, 3, 4],  7/14/15: [9], 7/13/15: [5, 6, 7, 8]]"
```

For **Swift 2.0**, you need to use `dates.enumerate()` instead.

Comment: Your code isn't working quite the way it was expected to work. When the user clicks the end button to the game, it stores the date and score inside the arrays dates and score. When I print the new dictionary(dic), it comes out differently. The date value comes out fine, but when there are multiple of the same date values, the number of date values multiply the number of numbers in the score array. If dates = [7/12/15,7/12/15], and score = [100,200], dic = [7/12/15: 100, 200, 100, 200]. Do you know a fix? Thanks! I checked the other answers, and Leo's answer generates the same problem.

Comment: It sounds like you are running the `for loop` a second time.  Are you remembering to reinitialize the `dic` to clear it out first?  Do a `dic = [:]` to set it back to empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
    let  score = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,]
    let  dates = ["7/12/15","7/12/15","7/12/15","7/12/15","7/13/15","7/13/15","7/13/15","7/13/15"," 7/14/15"]
    var dic = [String:[Int]]()
    for var index=0;index < dates.count; index++ {
        let key = dates[index];
        var value = dic[key]
        if value == nil{
            dic[key] = [score[index]]
        }else{
            value!.append(score[index])
            dic[key] = value
        }
    }
    println(dic)
```

This will log

```
[7/12/15: [1, 2, 3, 4],  7/14/15: [9], 7/13/15: [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: You were faster :( I struggled with this syntax `var dic = [String:[Int]]()`... Thanks for that anyway ;)

Comment: Please use Swift style for loops.  `for index in 0..<dates.count` (or the `enumerate` function)

Answer (score 1):

```
func zipToDict<
  S0 : SequenceType,
  S1 : SequenceType where
  S0.Generator.Element : Hashable
  >(keys: S0, values: S1) -> [S0.Generator.Element:[S1.Generator.Element]] {
    var dict: [S0.Generator.Element:[S1.Generator.Element]] = [:]
    for (key, value) in zip(keys, values) {
      dict[key] = (dict[key] ?? []) + [value]
    }
    return dict
}

let score = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
let dates = ["7/12/15","7/12/15","7/12/15","7/12/15","7/13/15","7/13/15","7/13/15","7/13/15","    7/14/15"]

print(zipToDict(dates, score)) // [7/12/15: [1, 2, 3, 4], 7/14/15: [9], 7/13/15: [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```