# 2 arrays into one dictionary while maintaining the indexes

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I have two separate arrays that I want to import into a dictionary.  Order is extremely important because both arrays must match in index

```
struct MyVariables {
    static var users:NSArray!
    static var img:NSArray!
}

    var data = SearchVC.getData()
    MyVariables.users = data.users;  //array 1  (key)
    MyVariables.img = data.img;      //array 2


// Goal is to insert these arrays into a dictionary while maintaing the matching indexes on both arrays
// Dictonary (MyVariables.img, key: MyVariables.users)
```

Comment: You should edit your question to ask a specific question or state what you have tried and what problem you have encountered. As it stands now, I am voting to close.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining 2 arrays into a dictionary in Xcode 6, swift?, with corresponding index values)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368372/combining-2-arrays-into-a-dictionary-in-xcode-6-swift-with-corresponding-inde)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `key` in a dictionary in swift must be `hashable`. i.e., not `AnyObject`.

Assuming you can replace some of your untyped Swift arrays, or cast them like so:

```
struct MyVariables {
    var users:Array<AnyObject>
    var img:Array<String>
}
```

then you can iterate through 1 array using a preferred Swift method and access the second using indexing:

```
var dictionary = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()

for (index, element) in enumerate(MyVariables.img) {
    dictionary[element] = MyVariables.users[index]
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  I had to switch img and users because I have duplicate img and it wasn't getting the result

Answer (score 1):

A Dictionary does not have a particular order. However, if both arrays have the same length, it is quite easy to iterate over them together:

```
var dictionary = [NSString: AnyObject]()
for var index = 0; index < data.users.count; index++ {
    let img = data.img as! NSString
    dictionary[img] = data.users[index]
}
```

Or, as @robertvojta suggested, use the `zip()` method:

```
var dictionary = [NSString: AnyObject]()
for (user, image) in zip(data.users, data.img) {
    let img = image as! NSString
    dictionary[img] = user
}
```

Comment: `for (index, user) in enumerate(users)` or `users.enumerate()` (Swift 2) is better, because it helps you to avoid `= 0`, `<`, `++`, ... errors in for loops.

Comment: type AnyObject does not conform to protocol Hashable

Comment: @DevTonio right - can you tell me which type the `img` are?

Comment: They are both NSArray, I just replaced both anyobject with NSArray

Comment: Sorry, I meant the contents of `img`. Are those string, images, etc. I need the exact type.

Comment: img is a NSString (encoded base 64)... Then later in my code I add them into an array using componentsSeparatedByString

Comment: Or Swift style loops are better as well ... `for index in 0..<data.users.count {...}`. In this way you're not forced to use `var index` ...

Comment: Isn't `var dictionary = [String: AnyObject]` more elegant, and compress the inner loop on a single line: `dictionary[img as! String] = user` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop for travels the array in that as per index access keys and values respective array and add it in dictionary. Its so simple so you can achive your goal using it.

I hope it will help you!